# How do I set ActiveSheet in ActiveWorkbook as the window on the top of the screen?

Tags: vba, excel

I attempted to run a `UserForm` that collects data from `Workbook("A")` and outputs result to either to `Workbook("A")` or `Workbook("B")`(a different one).

If the result is sent to Workbook("B"), I would use `Workbook("B").Activate`, `Sheets(1).Activate`.

But after the UserForm is unloaded and the macro is completed, I am still in the `Workbook("A")`, even though the title of the workbook is shaded (which means that Workbook("A") is not AciveWorkbook).

How do I bring the real ActiveWorkbook `Workbook("B")` to the top of my computer screen?

Comment: Without seeing your coding, we can do nothing but guess. Can you provide the portion of this code? One thing I can think of is the you forget to do `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`, but it is a guess naturally

Comment: @Tehscript I can't post my code because it's too many. But I do have `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`. BTW, I feel this problem is related tot windowstate property.

Comment: @Nicholas `Application.ScreenUpdating` does not do anything for you.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Set wb1 = Workbooks("A")
Set wb2 = Workbooks("B")
wb2.Sheets(1).Activate
```